# Draw camera position using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I am quite new to OpenCV so please forgive me if I am asking something obvious.

I have a program that gives me position and rotation of moving camera. But to be sure if my program works correctly I want to draw those results in 3 coordinate system.

I also have camera projection matrix

```
Camera matrix: [1135,52           0    1139,49
                      0     1023,50     543,50
                      0           0          1]
```

example how my result looks (calculated camera position):

```
                Position = [ 0,92725     0,041710  -0,372177    0,0803997
                            -0,0279857  -0,983288  -0,1179896  -0,0466907
                             0,373459   -0,177219   0,910561,   1,19969
                             0           0          0           1         ]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify something first: Do you have 2 cameras ? (i.e. do you want to _project_ `movingCamera` onto `observerCamera`'s viewport using the `imagePosition = 3dPosition * extrinsicMatrix * intrinsicMatrix` formula ?) Or, do you have a single (moving) camera which position you want to represent in a 3D scene ? (e.g. a 3D viewer or such visualizer)

Comment: I have only one/single moving camera which position I want to represent in a 3D scene ar as you sad in 3D viewer/visualizer.